# Do you see a big difference between squashing 2 commits or amending the first one?

Tags: git, github, workflow

I'm curious how you would consider these 2 manners of cleaning a git history before pushing it (before the merge of a pull request. Is one of them making more sens than the other ?

The question is not only technical but also 'conceptual' regarding the way it can modify the workflow in a development team.

Say that :

- I have a commit A
- I pushed it to a dedicated branch meant to be used as a pull request
- I then add some code which "enhances" the first commit

Solution 1 : Commit B, push & share, then squash A & B into A'

Solution 2 : Amend the first one with `git add /path/to/thefile && git commit --amend`, then `git push` with the `-f` option

As far as I'm concerned, I **think** (but I'm not sure...) that there's technically no difference since the git history is rewritten and the commit signature/md5 will change. The only difference is that solution 1, when working in a team, helps in the pull request discussion by keeping the commits history until they are squashed into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once anyone downstream of your commits gets your work, you shouldn't rebase, as you're changing history and next time someone pulls it'll be different from what they last saw and if they based their changes on it, they'll have to locally rebase on your changes again.

This means that you shouldn't do solution 1 as you're "releasing" A and B then removing them locally and creating C (you call it A' but it's really a completely different commit). What are you then going to do after squashing these 2 commits? You don't mention pushing it back to the remote which still has A and B? You have locally a different history to the remote, so you're going to get pain down the line.

Solution 2 at least pushes the final result from your local repo to a remote, but everyone else will still need to pull those changes in and rebase anything they have done. If this is, as you say, a branch used for pull requests, then you at least may get away with noone having picked up and based anything on your changes, but if they've already merged your pull-request branch they'll have to do it all again.

What's wrong with having 2 commits in the pull request branch?